# Trying to filter elements from a map gives "cannot move" because of a field being String

Tags: rust

I'm having a `HashMap<u8, Item>` where `Item` is a struct containing among other fields, a String:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Item {
    name: String,
    kind: u8,
    accepted_values: Vec<u8>
}
```

I'm trying, to get the items in the HashMap that contain a specific values in its `accepted_values` property:

```
type ItemDatabase = HashMap<u8,Item>;
pub trait ItemDatabaseExtension {
    fn filter(&self, find_by: u8) -> ItemDatabase;
}

impl ItemDatabaseExtension for ItemDatabase {
    fn filter(&self, find_by: u8) -> ItemDatabase {
        let filtered_map = self
            .iter()
            .filter(|(_, &value)| {
                value.accepted_values.contains(&room_type)
            })
            .map(|(&key, &value)| {
                (key, value)
            })
            .collect();
        
        return filtered_map;
    }
}
```

The idea was to get a copy of the elements. At least I have no intention to modify them.

However, compiler is complaining cannot move the value in filter because Item does not implement the trait `Copy`. The problem is `Item` contains a `String` field and that disallows (as long as I know) the struct to implement `Copy`:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
  --> item.rs:52:22
   |
52 |             .filter(|(_, &value)| {
   |                      ^^^^^-----^
   |                           |
   |                           data moved here
   |                           move occurs because `value` has type `item::Item`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm quite new to Rust,so I don't fully understand how to master the borrowing issues one may face.
I understand the simple examples I can find in the rust documentation, but not when I face them in more "complex" scenarios.

I've tried removing the `&` on both `.filter(|(_,value)|` and `.map(|(&key,value)|`, but that only moves the error to the `.collect()` call with:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `HashMap<u8, item::Item>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `(u8, &item::Item)`
    --> item.rs:58:14
     |
58   |             .collect();
     |              ^^^^^^^ value of type `HashMap<u8, item::Item>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=(u8, &item::Item)>`
```

Basically I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Removing the reference from `filter()` is a correct step. Then, you can replace `.map(|(&key, &value)| (key, value))` with `.map(|(&key, value)| (key, value.clone()))`.

Comment: So.. I was in the right direction, only missing the clone call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can only destructure a reference with the `&v` pattern when the referred to type implements `Copy`, since you implement `Clone` you can just use that instead:

```rust
impl ItemDatabaseExtension for ItemDatabase {
    fn filter(&self, room_type: u8) -> Self {
        self.iter()
            .filter_map(|(&key, value)| {
                value
                    .accepted_values
                    .contains(&room_type)
                    .then(|| (key, value.clone()))
            })
            .collect();
    }
}
```

Further you can combine the `filter` followed by `map` into a single `filter_map` like I did above.
[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a04a220aeb35ebb4e165a2ccf9dc8c0)